# Access values on remote python script from local python script

Tags: python, remote-access

I am a team member which is developing autonomous fixed-wing. I am using ros to control fixed-wing.
In mission script there are callback functions which is giving latitude, longtitude, altitude, compass_angle, velocity, battery_level

In local computer I ve got a ground station which shows callback function values on indicator by using Tkinter and PIL

I am getting values from firebase using firebase_admin but It is not real-time, values reach ground-computer 3-4 seconds late.

So I want to connect remote computer , reach mission_script.py and get values on callback functions. Is it possible to do if it is How can I do it?

Comment: Have you considered storing values on txt files (on a server ?) with the first computer and accessing it via the second computer ?

Comment: Use ZeroMQ to send the data directly from the device to groundstation. Since it is brokerless, it is very fast en fault tolerant.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Alex's comment I used ZMQ and get real time data flow.